# Error on Part.getSubmittedFileName

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I am uploading a file, and I use `javax.servlet.http.Part` in the Servlet. It seems to behave strangely, since `part.getSubmittedFileName()` is returning an error (it seems a `POST http://localhost:8080/.... 500 (Internal Server Error)` ) so I have to use the old JEE 6 method to obtain the name. **What could be happening?** I tried to capture the error with a `try-catch` but when the sentence is executed, it just leaves the Servlet method entirely without entering into the catch block.

---

```
@MultipartConfig
@WebServlet(name = "UploadServlet", urlPatterns = {"/uploadServlet"})
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Part partFile = request.getPart("file");
    ....
    try {
        System.out.println("submName " + partFile.getSubmittedFileName()); // never prints
        String fileName = partFile.getSubmittedFileName();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EX: " + e); // never executes
    }
    ....
}
}
```

Comment: Ask one question per Question.

Comment: share the code snippet, svp.